# is wordpress suitable for a large database querying?

Tags: php, wordpress

Wonder if anyone has any advice on a project I might be picking up.

It's a bit vague at the mo, but I think basically a scientific app as in you supply a product which is then checked against a database of proteins to see if it has a reaction.

From the information I did get - this could really be any scenario, and sounds quite simple dev wise - the user on the site fills out a form which then checks in some way against a db of other similar attributes to see if it's suitable, it then gets also added to that db at the end (so the db potentially grows as each user does a check).

The part I'm wondering about is this could be potentially huge (eg 10,000 + unlimited) - so would anything be gained from building a custom php app to handle all this, as in would wordpress not be suitable for backend - and should I be catering for time intensive queries ?

Thanks for looking

Comment: There's a big difference between 10,000 and "huge". But it depends specifically on what type of queries you're running. Could you give an example (made up, I realize you're in scoping mode) of a query you think might need to be run... pseudo-code is fine

Comment: Think its more to do with the database and how it is indexed than WordPress.  WordPress is just PHP.  Not too sure about its model/data layer but say its some table/row/gateway approach, that code specifically should not be the bottle neck.  More about the SQL and how its handled on database server.  Does not sound like you need some cache intensive DAL/ORM for this.  Think it should be fine.

Comment: Hi, yeah it's scoping at the moment, I realise it's a bit vague. From when the guy was talking it would be a a number of attributes describing the product, such as name, attribute 1,2 etc - and I think he did mention there could references to supporting PDF's etc (which I'm guessing would just be links to a stored folder).

Comment: I was thinking of using wordpress for the front end anyhow - for back stuff like this I usually would just build in plugins/direct into templates at the moment. Was concerned my approach might not be robust enough, and the app might struggle.

Comment: Wordpress is not going to affect it if you just store the data in a custom table. The real question is how complex you queries are going to be. If you are just injecting data from a form that should be no problem at all. Pulling product info is no problem either. 

I recently did similar with a Joomla site and made a custom back end for requests in EXTjs and looking back one of the lessons I learned was I made it way too complicated. I would wait until you have all your information before you make a decision, but from what you said here I see not major problems with the size.

Comment: I think it will be just simple one in one out record pulling, at this moment I don't think i will have to join tables etc. The query will probably be based on looking for one supplied criteria that might exist already in any of the entries, if not get added. then return a dynamic single page suited to the user.

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

See ticket http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/9864 (Performance issues with large number of pages).  I filed this ticket 3+ years ago, and there is still no resolution. Since that time, the code in question got even more complicated, and started using a heavier version of ther internal query library.

Those severe issues are with pages, but posts are equally taxing in queries. And if you have meta-data, it starts taxing the server even further.  To top this off, most leading caching plugins for WP exclude web robots, so every few weeks when google, baidu and yandex start hammering your machine for the 10k pages, it'll bring your machine down.

This just means that you can't use it natively for large content sets, but you can still use most of WordPress with additional code customizations for parts that'll be outside of the WP database/construct.

**Edit**: to clarify- what I was saying is that solely using WP's native database structure, as defined by [this schema in the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description), and query_posts() / WP_Query() to perform the queries is the inefficiency I was referring to.  The native WP storage/query system doesn't handle large volumes of pages / posts very efficiently.  However, bypassing some of the native functionality will likely work fine.

Comment: Hi, thanks - I'm going to see if I can get some more details but I get the feeling the form will be submitted then approved manually (i Think to avoid duplicates..but I reckon I could cater for duplicates anyhow by locking the db per user perhaps), so I'm guessing that in the end all that will be returned is one dynamic page viewable through the users personal login. I'm pretty sure this is how it will go, I'm going to try and extract some more info though